# Can't connect from Excel to SQL Server 2017 on Windows / On Mac it works

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have the following setup: A Windows Server running SQL Server 2017 joined to a domain. Some groups of the AD Domain have the permission set to sysadmin and public.

When I open Excel (Version 1908) on the server and try to connect a sheet over the SQL Server function using Windows Authentication everything works. When I try the same with Excel on a non Domain Joined MacBook using the Microsoft ODBC driver and NTLM authentification it works too with the same credentials. Using a non Domain Joined Windows machine (Windows 10) and Windows authentication (alternate signin information) with DOMAIN\username the authentification fails.

When the authentication from the Windows machine fails the SQL Server shows this in his logs:
[image: SQL Error]

All of these test were made using the same credentials and it was tested on multiple different Windows machines. Every time with the same results. Note: Login over SQL Credentials works on every computer.

What could be the reason that it works on the server and on Mac but not on the Windows machines? What is different?

EDIT: For testing purposes I have setup an VM and joined it the domain as mentioned in the comments. The authentification seems to work now. Atleast it doesn't say anymore that the credentials are incorrect. I am now getting this error: [image] Extra info: the database is running as local user not a domain user.

Comment: Did you try user@domain in stead of domain\user ? If your domain has a hierarchy did your try the full domain name ? (E.g "user@country.company.com", where normally you would only use the country part.) Sometimes you need to play with the variants to get it to work.

Comment: @Tonny these variatons were also tried

Comment: Mmmhh... How exactly are you supplying the domain credentials (that "alternate signin information" you mentioned) to the ODBC source? If memory serves it is either the current Window user or SQL authentication. There is no way (as far as I know) to supply alternative Windows credentials...

Comment: @Tonny in Excel 2019 you have 3 Options Windows, Database or Microsoft account. Under Windows you get 2 radio buttons one with current cridentials and one with alternative credentials. If you check alternative credentials you can enter a Windows username and password

Comment: @Tonny Looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/x88x25B

Comment: Ahah... That's new in Excel 2019/365. I hadn't discovered that feature yet. I just played around with it in Excel 365 and I'm also having problems with it. Alternative credentials only seems to work in the same domain the computer is in. I've got 2 accounts in different sub-domains of our AD forrest, both with MS-SQL access and I can only use the one that exists in the same sub-domain as my laptop. The other one gives me an "impersonation failure". While "Run As different user" for Excel under that second account does work. But Run As won't work for you as you have a non-domain PC.

Comment: @Tonny the devices are only Azure AD registered and not joined. The server is joined to the Azure AD. So if you are correct it isn't going to work in my setup? Wonder why it is working on the Mac with NTLM authentification.

Comment: Mac's are never fully registered into the Domain (You can add a Mac but it isn't quite the same as a Windows system). So I presume there is some provision made on the Mac version of the software to make it work, but on the Windows version that just isn't there. I'm afraid you are out of luck.

Comment: @Tonny I could test it now with a fully joined vm and it accepts now the credentials but I receive a new error as mentioned in my now edited question. Maybe you now a solutions for this?